# Twilio completed room - can it be rejoined/recreated?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I'm using the REST API to create rooms. In the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks#rooms-callbacks), it says a room will end when empty for 5 minutes. I would like to know what this means when trying to reuse the same room. Can participants rejoin that room again?

My use case is that users make request to join a room via a server endpoint. A [check by `UniqueName`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource?code-sample=code-retrieve-an-in-progress-room-instance-by-uniquename&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) is performed to see if this room exists. If it does not, it is then [created](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-room&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) using the `UniqueName`.

There will certainly be cases where a room is created but is empty for more than 5 minutes, and I would like to re-use the same `UniqueName` to join the room (empty, completed or otherwise). But it's not clear to me that this can be done once a room is completed.

E.g., if another user tries to join the completed room, will the logic from above still work, or will it break b/c the room is in `completed` status can cannot be joined or re-created? My goal is to always have access to a room with the same `UniqueName`.

Please advise, thanks.

**Edit**

I just had a thought to instead [retrieve a list of rooms by `UniqueName`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource?code-sample=code-retrieve-a-list-of-rooms-by-uniquename&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x), which would show me a room that has already been created, regardless of its status. However, I would still need to be able to use the same room if its status is `completed`.

Can the status be updated from `completed` to `in-progress`?

**Update**

It would seem that the status [cannot be updated](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/53112) from `completed` to `in-progress`. So, when a room is completed, how I can I continue to use the same `UniqueName` for another room if one already exists with that unique name?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question here as I think I have a solution.

After tinkering with the Twilio quickstart app, I discovered that the `UniqueName` is unique in the context of rooms that are `in-progress`. I verified this by joining and leaving a room multiple times within a few seconds. A new room was created every time I left. I wasn't aware of this, but rooms created via client SDK will close instantly after all participants leave. As stated in the docs, rooms created via the REST API remain open for 5 minutes.

When I say "created", I mean that a new room with a new `SID` is created and can be viewed in the Twilio console, **even if the UniqueName has not changed**. So you can in fact have multiple rooms with the same `UniqueName`, but only the room with status `in-progress` is evaluated against when making REST API calls.

Thus, the answer would be to simply try to create a room with a unique name. Doing so when the room exists results in a 404 error as stated in the docs. Ie:

```
{ [Error: Room exists]
  status: 400,
  message: 'Room exists',
  code: 53113,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/53113',
  detail: undefined }
```

However, if a room with that unique name was already `completed`, a new room with the same unique name can be created. The simplest approach would be to try/catch on creating a room and handle the error.

```
  let room;

  try {
    room = await client.video.rooms.create({uniqueName: 'test'})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. I'm glad you worked through this. I found, when trying to do something similar, that you can try to [fetch the room by `uniqueName`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource?code-sample=code-create-a-room&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) which only returns `in-progress` rooms, and catch and create the room if it doesn't exist. That way around you get the room object with a maximum of 2 requests, but a minimum of 1 if the room exists.